# How can I load data from .txt efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

I am currently using fstream to load data, which is 7.1GB, with C++. The .txt file goes like this:

```
 item1  2.87  4.64  ... 
 item2  5.89  9.24  ... 
 ...     ...   ...  ...
```

It has 300000 rows and 201 columns (1 column for the item name and 200 for its weights) and each cell has a double type number. What I do now is like this:

```
ifstream click_log(R"(1.txt)", ifstream::in);
string line;
unordered_map<string, vector<double>> dict;
while (getline(click_log, line)){
    istringstream record(line);
    string key;
    vector<double> weights;
    double weight;
    record >> key;
    while (record >> weight){
        weights.push_back(weight);
    }
    dict[key] = weights;
}
```

However, it takes my computer (AMD 3700X, 8 cores) about 30 minutes to load the file completely.
Is it slow because its O(m*n) complexity or maybe simply the fact that converting string to double is slow?
What is the most efficient way to load data from .txt?

Comment: Most C compilers also have a profiling tool. Maybe try to find out where most of the time is spent. I suspect that a dictionary probably isn't the best data structure to use in this case. How about using an old-fashioned linear linked list (instead of an array with pre-allocated size)? Also, what is the time if you just read all lines from the file (discarding them)?

Comment: @U.Windl  I don't think I can use a linear linked list because the keys are discrete strings. If I using a list, I still have to use a dictionary to record the position of each item. If I just read all lines and do nothing with each line, it will have O(m) complexity and it only takes 30 seconds.

Comment: First thing, you should pre-allocate your vectors or use `std::array` instead since the size is well known (same thing for the dictionnary). It would remove a lot of deallocation/reallocation/copies due to `std::vector` machinery. Then you should write directly into the target container instead of using temporary vectors (and do a lot of extra copies). But I have a question, does your file contains "+-----+" too ? Or did you add it for readability ? It is very confusing because your code does not seem to handle that.

Comment: You could try to use a memory mapping for your file to speed up its loading.

Comment: How does this not throw an exception, when you are reading every line, but only every other line contains data? And you also have delimiters between the values which you are not taking into account?

Comment: Just did a quick test, it does not work. Either your code or your provided file is wrong.

Comment: @user1810087 My bad, the file does not contain "+-----+"

Comment: @Fareanor The file does not contain "+-----+"

Comment: Without a doubt, calling `weights.reserve(200)` before reading in the weights will be a significant improvement.  This will have the additional benefit of the vector not being oversized.  Secondly, using move-semantics to add it to the map will help prevent an extra copy.  Finally, reserving enough buckets on your `unordered_map` will help avoid re-hashing which is also expensive.  Consider using `std::map` as an alternative, if you're not sure.

Comment: Note also that even parsing `double` values from strings is a non-trivial cost.  If you know your data is always conforming to a specific format (e.g. always decimal notation), consider rolling your own simplified `double` value parser, if profiling shows it to be significant after making these other optimizations.  And if you can get away with storing `float` instead of `double` (assuming you don't need high precision), this will almost halve your memory footprint.

Comment: Another consideration here is you are doing this entirely single threaded and waiting for a blocking I/O operation before you process each line of the file. You should be able to divide this work among all CPU threads. There should be an environment variable you can read to determine the number of CPU threads (not always the same as number of cores btw) and modern storage devices can do multiple reads in parallel so this would be worth looking into imo.

Comment: Probably not the core issue, but: `dict[key] = weights;` - this line is a copy assignment. Directly write stuff into `dict[key]` or at least do a move or use `std::vector::swap` - direct filling is better though.

Comment: Also, if you read a single file at several times, consider writing an algorithm that transforms it into a binary format, which would be far faster to read. Not sure if this applies to your particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should not recreate your variables at each loop iteration. Create them once and for all, then you can reassign them when needed.

If you want to use `std::vector` instead of `std::array<double, 200>`, then you should `reserve(200)` all of your vectors in order to avoid a lot of reallocations/copies/deallocations due to `std::vector`'s machinery.

You can do the same for your `std::unordered_map`.

Finally, write your data directly into the target container, you don't need to use that much of temporaries (it would remove the huge overhead caused by all these unnecessary copies).

I have rewritten your code with taking these guidelines into account. I bet it would increase your performances:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("..\\tests\\data\\some_data.txt"); // Replace with your file
    if(!ifs)
        return -1;
    
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::array<double, 200>> dict;
    dict.reserve(300000);
    
    std::string line;
    std::string key;
    double weight;
    std::size_t i;
    
    while(getline(ifs, line))
    {
        std::istringstream record(line);
        i = 0;
    
        record >> key;
    
        while(record >> weight)
        {
            dict[key].at(i++) = weight;
        }
    }

    ifs.close();

    // The whole file is loaded

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, I don't claim this to be the most efficient way to do it. I'm sure we can bring more improvements that I didn't thought of at this very moment.

Anyway, keep in mind that you will still probably have a bottleneck with hard drive access, IO operations,...